# Custom ServiceView w/ View On Top Crashes App/Phone After 6.5 Minutes

Tags: java, android, crash, admob, surfaceview

I'm writing a small game using a Custom SurfaceView.  I wanted to put an AdMob view over the bottom portion of the SurfaceView, but after running the app for about six minutes, the app throws an error and then reboots the phone.  I've replaced the AdMob view with a single button, and the error still occurs, so I assume the issues is caused by putting any view over the SurfaceView.  If I remove any views from over the top of the SurfaceView, the game runs fine indefinitely.

I've tried using layouts other than RelativeLayout, but the problem persists.  I'm wondering if anyone has run into this before, or has any other avenues to explore.

Custom SurfaceView:

```
public class AndroidFastRenderView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
{
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidFastRenderView";
    AndroidGame game;
    Bitmap framebuffer;
    Thread renderThread = null;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    volatile boolean running = false;

    public AndroidFastRenderView(AndroidGame game, Bitmap framebuffer)
    {
        super(game);
        this.game = game;
        this.framebuffer = framebuffer;
        this.holder = getHolder();
    }

    public AndroidFastRenderView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        running = true;
        renderThread = new Thread(this);
        renderThread.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Rect dstRect = new Rect(0,0,80,120);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (running)
        {
            if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }

            float deltaTime = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            game.getCurrentScreen().update(deltaTime);
            game.getCurrentScreen().present(deltaTime);

            Canvas canvas = null;

            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null)
            {
                dstRect = canvas.getClipBounds();
                canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, null);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Paused");
        running = false;
        while(true)
        {
            try {
                renderThread.join();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // retry
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Building the Interface in the main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    boolean isLandscape = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    int frameBufferWidth = isLandscape ? 120 : 80;
    int frameBufferHeight = isLandscape ? 80 : 120;

    Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth, frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

    float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    renderView  = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
    graphics    = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
    fileIO      = new AndroidFileIO(getAssets());
    audio       = new AndroidAudio(this);
    input       = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
    screen      = this.getStartScreen();

    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "GLGame");

    if (useAds)
    {
        //adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, AD_UNIT_ID);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

        //adView.setLayoutParams(params);

        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.addView(renderView);
        //layout.addView(adView);

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setText("Blargle");
        layout.addView(button);

        //adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        setContentView(layout);

    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(renderView);
    }
}
```

LogCat of the Error:

```
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceTextureClient(10342): dequeueBuffer failed (Broken pipe)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342): Exception locking surface
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:88)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:754)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:734)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at com.somethingutility.games.framework.impl.AndroidFastRenderView.run(AndroidFastRenderView.java:60)
01-25 13:50:18.084: E/SurfaceHolder(10342):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This error repeats till the phone reboots.

Comment: can you indicate (in your code above) line 60 in AndroidFastRenderView.java

Comment: Line 60: canvas = holder.lockCanvas(dstRect);

Comment: You are passing an empty `Rect` to `lockCanvas`.

Comment: I edited the code and checked the android source to see if I was pulling the dirty rectangle properly.  For grins, I set the initial rectangle to be the dimensions of the screen.  The app still crashes at the same spot after 6.5 minutes.

Comment: I checked "All messages" right before it crashed.  It barfed out:
01-25 18:08:43.097: W/Adreno200-GSL(3602): <gsl_ldd_control:225>: ioctl code 0xc00c092f (IOCTL_KGSL_GPMEM_ALLOC) failed: errno 12 Out of memory
As well as a memory dump.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid displaying the AdView over the SurfaceView by specifically setting the renderRiew to be `ABOVE` the AdView:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, renderView.getId());
```

You might need to give the renderView an ID if it doesn't have one.

Comment: This seems to be more of a band-aid than a solution.  It would work out fine if I plan on using a portrait orientation with a bar advertisement at the bottom or top, but it wouldn't be the most efficient way to get things done if I want to use a landscape orientation with an advertisement in the upper or lower right.  If for some reason, I need a button or some other view on top of the surfaceview, I'm back to the same issue.